# How to read and process xml data from stored procedure in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xml

I am calling a stored procedure like this:

```
usp_ReportResults @query = '759,905,1048,170,725,80129', 
                  @ReportName = 'GenRepot'
```

where `usp_ReportResult` is defined as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ReportResults]
     @query VARCHAR(MAX), 
     @ReportName VARCHAR(100), 
     @AutoSelectXML BIT = 1, 
     @XMLResult XML = NULL OUTPUT
```

I am trying to get result in `xml` variable to make further process as:

```
DECLARE @XMLRESULT xml

SET @XMLRESULT = exec usp_ReportResults @query = '759,905,1048,170,725,80129', @ReportName = 'GenRepot'
```

But I'm not able to get result in `@XMLRESULT` and unable to read and store data result from `xml` to table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `SET` the `XMLRESULT`.

You should pass it in as an `OUTPUT` parameter.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx

```
DECLARE @XMLRESULT xml;
EXEC usp_ReportResults @query = '759,905,1048,170,725,80129', @ReportName ='GenRepot', @XMLResult = @XMLRESULT OUTPUT;
```

You can then use the `@XMLRESULT` parameter, which has been populated with the result of the Stored Procedure.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.my_table(xml_field)
SELECT @XMLRESULT;
```